# Sending an array in header

Tags: php, arrays, header

I want to send an an array of 3-4 elements in header in an array . I want to get some advice whether it is a good practice ? The elements will be used only if he is a new user .

Comment: You want to send it in what header? What exactly do you mean by “in header in an array”?

Answer (score 0):

You can send as usual data with name with [] (ex. array[]=17&array[]=15 ), $_POST['array'] / $_GET['array'] will be array